# spring boot jdbcTemplate.query throws table not found auto converting table name to upper case

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

i have a jdbcTemplate.query method with query bit complex with multiple left joins, so its difficult for me to implement interface based repository methods.

I am using a MySQL db from AWS RDS.

when the query is executing spring boot jpa automatically converting table name to upper case and it throws error as: table not found.

exception is:

with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT DISTINCT test_desc FROM `test_name_table`]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TEST_NAME_TABLE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT DISTINCT test_desc FROM `test_name_table` [42102-200]] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TEST_NAME_TABLE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT DISTINCT test_desc FROM `test_name_table` [42102-200]

here are the solutions i have tried:

from application.properties:

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

database url:

spring.datasource.dataSourceProperties.serverName=test-instance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;

as you see above sql query, i have even put the table name inside backtick. but no luck.

I tried to rename the table name in MySQL to TEST_NAME_TABLE, but still no luck.

any recommended fix for this?

Comment: The error is from H2 not MySQL. So is probably a test. Use the actual database instead of H2.

Comment: oh i just renamed original table name with 'test_'. its not test cases result. this issue is happening as part of an api invocation.

Comment: looks like you have to set case insensitivity when [initializing the server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html#:~:text=Table%20names%20are%20stored%20in,database%20names%20and%20table%20aliases.)

Comment: You state you are using MYSQL, but clearly the error is for h2 `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException` as that is clearly an H2 class...

Comment: @M.Deinum - thanks for the tip, i printed the jdbc url and noted that its h2 url only, i fixed Spring.Datasource, now it works thanks

Answer (score -1):

its a good practice use `@Table(name = "table_name")` for a model and `@Column(name = "column_name")` annotation for every column in your Model.java

and use `@Query("some query in SQL")` for every query you use in ModelRepository.java

example:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id

    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "jobTitle")
    private String jobTitle;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "imagUrl")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "employeeCode")
    private String employeeCode;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Employee s WHERE s.email = ?1")
    Optional<Employee> findEmployeeByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: If you only set the column name, it is only needed if the column name differs between java class and database table. If they are the same, it is useless clutter without any effect. And for basic queries, the `@Query` annotation is not needed as well, as JPA can infer the query based on the method name

Comment: thanks for your reply. however my query is not straightforward as you have given, this query has too many left joins with multiple other tables so i could n't do this @Repository based interface method.

Comment: This advice totally beats the purpose of JPA (and the hibernaet strategies for mapping fields to columns) and the use of Spring Data JPA.